# In Flutter, how to create an UI like Uber to have map in middle and AppBar and navigate to different type of views

Tags: user-interface, flutter, navigation, stack

I am pretty new to Flutter. I am working on a project to create an UI like Uber to have google map in the background and have different type of views, such as full screen address input view(it seems full screen but part of the view can be hidden to expose the map behind and interact with it), persistent bottom sheets and some floating button on top. Using stack to put one bottom sheet on the map is not difficult. But when it comes to navigate back and forth between different type of views while keeping the map in the background and the map is still touchable, I am not sure how to manage it. Sometimes it navigate 2-3 times deep and back to the first bottom sheet. So the question is:

How to implement a way to navigate between different type of views, like firstly pull up full screen address view, pop the address view after entering address and pull up car type view as the sample image shown on the link below. And press on the back button on top left corner will go back to address view.

If you have any idea how to design this navigation flow, please share it. Thank you.
 [Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjqJh.jpg)

Update: found this GitHub repository demonstrating how to implement Uber like UI. I am checking it out. 
https://github.com/iamSahdeep/fu_uber

Answer (score 2):

For background maps with elements on top, a `Stack` is best as you mentioned.

For persistent bottom sheets, use the [BottomSheet class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)

For the floating button, use the [FloatingActionButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

For the navigation between BottomSheets only, you might want to learn more about this plugin [Modal Bottom Sheet](https://jamesblasco.github.io/modal_bottom_sheet/#/). It has exactly what you need. Check the "Cupertino Modal with inside Navigation".

Comment: Hello Bilaal, thanks for replying. As I understand the push route will display a full screen page and cover up the google map screen and will not be able to interact with the map. How to keep the map at the background and navigate between bottom sheet? Thank you.

Comment: Ahh ok
Edited the ans. Check it :)

Comment: Thank you. This seems good. But they are all modal bottom sheet that blocks all background interaction? Cheers

Comment: You can always put a container within the model bottom sheet and give it a fixed height. That way it won't take the whole screen.

Comment: Will play around with it. Thank you. What if I have different type of views to navigate back and forth, e.g. first display a full screen address input view, after that, display a summary bottom view as shown in the picture attached in my post. There is a float back button on the top left corner to allow user to go back to full screen address view. How to implement the floating back button to navigate between two different type of views? Thank you